# javascript: end and start DATE control

Tags: javascript, php, date

Well. my problem is the DATE control which comes from a browser calendar (example the default chrome calendar) after entering a date from this calendar, the latter is of type mm / dd / yyyy
but the data that I find on the database after the entry is of type yyyy / mm / dd
here is the code of my html form :

```
 
<form  name=formu action="ajouter_semestre.php"  method="POST">  
<input type="date" placeholder="date debut semestre" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['date_debut_sem'])){echo $_POST['date_debut_sem'];} ?>" maxlength="10" name="date_debut_sem" id="date_debut_sem" required><br>
<input type="date" placeholder="date  Fin du semestre" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['date_fin_sem'])){echo $_POST['date_fin_sem'];} ?>" maxlength="10" name="date_fin_sem" id="date_fin_sem" required><br>
</form>
```

and here is my js controller script

```
 
<script> 
 with(document.formu) {
    onsubmit = function() {
      tabdeb = (date_debut_sem.value.split(/[- //]/));
      tabfin = (date_fin_sem.value.split(/[- //]/));
      Odeb = new Date(tabdeb[2],tabdeb[1],tabdeb[0]);
      Ofin = new Date(tabfin[2],tabfin[1],tabfin[0]);
      if(Odeb > Ofin) {
        alert('date fin du semestre doit etre superieure a la date du debut')
        date_debut_sem.focus(); date_fin_sem.style.backgroundColor='#F00';
        return false
      };
    };
  };
</script>
```

Since it only controls the days
THANKS if you have read this far

Comment: You have a couple of references to `ds_sh` but that function is not present in the code you posted, so your example is not runnable. Please read [mcve]. Also, you can turn your two separate code blocks into a single runnable stack-snippet.

Comment: ok I understand . so, I updated my code, it only control days, no month or years

Comment: Can you edit a formal question into your post? I think I understand your dilemma, a date format mismatch, but for sake of clarity, a question would be really helpful.

Comment: Please see [MDN regarding *with* statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), their use is strongly discouraged. The date parse is flawed (month should be -1), the values are ISO 8601 formatted dates (YYYY-MM-DD) so can be compared lexically without conversion to Date, e.g. `date_debut_sem.value > date_fin_sem.value` is sufficient. Putting a semicolon after a block is just a redundant empty statement, don't do it.

Comment: RobG I tried but it doesn't work, my goal is the end and start date control whatever the technology, so I found my wish in jquery and jquery-ui. I will share it for student's like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hi**
My goal is to find a way to control the start and end date, after a little research I found a solution but with jquery and jquery-ui technology (user interface)
so i add these CDN link in the :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

then I totally removed the type = "date" attribute so as not to trigger the default browser calendar, I added the readonly = "readonly" attribute so that the user cannot enter manually

here is my form:

```
<form  name=formu action="ajouter_semestre.php"  method="POST">
<input readonly="readonly" placeholder="date debut semestre" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['date_debut_sem'])){echo $_POST['date_debut_sem'];} ?>" maxlength="10" name="date_debut_sem" id="txtFrom" class="calendrier" required><br>
<input readonly="readonly" placeholder="date  Fin du semestre" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['date_fin_sem'])){echo $_POST['date_fin_sem'];} ?>" maxlength="10" name="date_fin_sem" id="txtTo" class="calendrier" required><br>
```

finally the jquery script is as follows:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
numberOfMonths:1,
dateFormat:'yy/mm/dd',
onSelect:function(selectdate){
var dt = new Date(selectdate);
dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)
$("#txtTo").datepicker("option","minDate",dt);
}
});
$("#txtTo").datepicker({
numberOfMonths:1,
dateFormat:'yy/mm/dd',
onSelect:function(selectdate){
var dt = new Date(selectdate);
dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-1)
$("#txtFrom").datepicker("option","maxDate",dt);
}
});
});
</script>
```

dear reading pay attention to the   [jQuery date format](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)
Thank you